# Install pass-import in Fedora

Tags: fedora, password-store

I've installed pass-import via pip.

```
pip install pass-import
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pass-import in ./.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from pass-import) (23.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zxcvbn in /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from pass-import) (4.4.28)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from pass-import) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages (from pyaml->pass-import) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from requests->pass-import) (3.2.0)Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from requests->pass-import) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from requests->pass-import) (1.26.18)
```

but when I try to execute:

```
pass import bitwarden bitwarden_export_20240104164527.json
Error: import is not in the password store.
```

This is my path:

```
/home/hhlp/.local/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/p4v/bin:/opt/p4v/bin
```

but I think is not enough to make it work.

https://github.com/roddhjav/pass-import#readme

one solution is this, from fedora COPR repo just enable and install it

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/tofik/password-store/packages/

```
sudo dnf copr enable tofik/password-store
```

and then install it

```
sudo dnf install pass-import
```

but I would like to do it with the official one under pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pass-import` you installed from `pip` is an extension for Passwordstore.  According to your posted error, Passwordstore has no knowledge of the extension you installed.

Your error has nothing to do with your `PATH`, and installing from COPR would likely install a package that installs the extension into the correct location.

The output you posted from your install command states "Defaulting to user installation" so the `pass-import` extension would likely be installed somewhere locally.  Try to find out where with `find ~ -path \*/lib/password-store/\* -name import\*`.

You should be following the instructions for installing the extension locally and make sure to set the `PASSWORD_STORE_ENABLE_EXTENSIONS` and `PASSWORD_STORE_EXTENSIONS_DIR` environment variables as instructed in the [documentation](https://github.com/roddhjav/pass-import#readme).  Make sure `PASSWORD_STORE_EXTENSIONS_DIR` points to the directory containing the extension.

Comment: This did the trick, `export PASSWORD_STORE_EXTENSIONS_DIR="$(python -m site --user-site)/usr/lib/password-store/extensions/"`, thx for your time...